# react-native-vision-camera makes React Native Expo build to fail

Tags: react-native, build, expo, react-native-vision-camera

Currently, I am in the lasts steps of lunching a React Native Expo App, but when I try to do a build, it fails and I keep getting different errors for the react-native-vision-camera.

Does anyone have an ideia or solution for this issue?

react-native: 0.71.6,
expo: ~48.0.10,
react-native-vision-camera: ^2.15.4

Thank you!

I've tried (in different occasions) to:

1. enable Hermes
2. disable Hermes
3. make changes to a/node_modules/react-native-vision-camera/ios/React Utils/MakeJSIRuntime.h
   `#include <React_jsc/JSCRuntime.h>`

The issue is that nothing seems to work and every time I get a different error message

The most current one is:
Ex:

`The following build commands failed: ▸   Ld /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/xxxxx/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/VisionCamera.framework/VisionCamera normal (in target 'VisionCamera' from project 'Pods')`

[build fails1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cmd8o.png)
[buid fails2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/madBe.png)